# parsing base64 blob from tool output

Tags: c#, regex, base64

I have a problem parsing base64 encoded blob from tool output.
I'm using this regex in c#: **@"(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)"**

Everything worked fine until the blob I receive looks like following (it does not have even one '='. according to wiki base64 string can have 0-2 "=" signs in the end/)
I cannot work with string before and after the blob because it can be muli-language

> Provisioning the computer account... Successfully provisioned
>   [user-1009-1-] in the domain [testauto.sof]. Provisioning data was
>   saved successfully to
>   [C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\user-1009-1-.blob]. Provisioning
>   string (2624l bytes):
>
> 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
>
> Computer account provisioning completed successfully. The operation
>   completed successfully.

Anyone can help me to fix the regex?
Here is regex calculator that I using:
http://regex101.com/r/wP3kP9/1

Answer (score 0):

The following should work successfully:

```
^(?!$)(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=)?$
```

[regex101](http://regex101.com/r/cJ8jV6/2)

In my understanding, if no `=` is present, it's because the string length is a multiple of 4.

I also anchored it with `^`...`$`and used the `m` option so only your base64 string matches. I added `(?!$)` so empty lines don't match (couldn't simply change the `*` to `+` because you may want to match  short strings like `aa==`).